# Swift optional value Unwrap in while loop condition

Tags: ios, swift, linked-list

In the following code, the compiler complains that "value of optional type 'ListNode?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

The code is for manipulating a linked list:

```
var cur: ListNode? = head
while (cur != nil){ // this line has error
    cur = cur.next
}
```

My question is how to fix the error given that cur is declared as optional? I've check answers for other unwrap but this condition is within a while loop condition.

Comment: Can't reproduce...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I strongly assume that error actually occurs on the `cur = cur.next` line, because `cur` is an optional. The "quick and dirty" fix would be 
to unwrap it forcefully:

```
var cur: ListNode? = head
while cur != nil {
    // do something with `cur!` ...

    cur = cur!.next
}
```

But the proper solution is to use optional binding, which works not
only in combination with `if` but also with `while`:

```
var cur: ListNode? = head
while let node = cur {
    // do something with `node` ...

    cur = node.next
}
```

Comment: You are right. After updating to swift 2.2 it points to correct location of error. Didn't check which swift version it was before. Thanks!